Как определить resource.customizations для приложения argocd в локальном кластере kubernetes?
Вопрос возник при пробном использовании приложения ArgoCD в локальном кластере kubernetes.
У приложения ArgoCD есть описанный баг с зависающим статусом HEALTH в Progressing.
Одно из решений указано - определить custom health в argocd-cm ConfigMap приложения.
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/health/
В этом и вопрос - как именно это делатся?
Взял yaml установки ArgoCD
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml
В нем в разделе для ConfigMap для name: argocd-cm добавил "workaround",
data:
  resource.customizations:
  ...

но не совсем понимаю какие  <group/kind> надо определять?
В ArgoCD статус Progressing висит у сервиса развернутого через него деплоя,
т.е. Kind, видимо - Service.
А группа какая должна быть?
Попробовал так, не помогло:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
  name: argocd-cm
data:
  resource.customizations: |
    networking.k8s.io/Service:
      health.lua: |
        hs = {}
        hs.status = "Healthy"
        return hs
---

